# Can't get the value of two numbers in C# to add after

Tags: c#

so I'm trying to ask two numbers to the use to after that add later and call them with a `Console.Write()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

First I created three intengers, 
            `int num1 = 0;
            int num2 = 0;
            int num3 = 0;`

And then did this:

```
                Console.WriteLine("What's the first number?");
                num1 = Console.Read();
                Console.WriteLine("What's the second number?");
                num2 = Console.Read();
                num3 = num1 + num2;
                Console.WriteLine(num3);
```

And for some reason it is not working, it is giving me a value of 60+ without me even typing the second number.

Any help would be appreciated and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you pressing enter after entering first number? If yes, then you should consider using ReadLine instead of Read

Comment: Yeah Thanks Man!!

Comment: Google `c# console add two numbers` and [here](http://csharpsense.blogspot.com/2013/02/simple-c-program-to-add-two-numbers.html) is the homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Console.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a character value, not the number entered. Plus, it only returns the first character typed in. You should be using [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

You can try the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("What's the first number?");
int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("What's the second number?");
int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int num3 = num1 + num2;
Console.WriteLine(num3);
```

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a string so you'll need to convert the value to an `int`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ajva Glad to help! Make sure you accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem. Cheers!